# probability that one pack is not a derangement of the other one

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

If I place 2 packs of n cards each on a table and shuffle them, how do I calculate the probability that one pack is not a derangement of the other one?

Comment: Well, the first one can be arranged however, so it's just the probability that the second one is not a derangement.

Comment: @lulu but how do I do this

Comment: How many derangements are there?  How many permutations are there?

Comment: @lulu how many derangements are there

Comment: Look up [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)